# Animated Polar Plot

Tags: animation, plot, polar-coordinates

I am trying to make an animated plot of planetary motion using python. I can get the correct path to show up when not animated but once I try to animate it, it just shows up blank even though r and i are being output as the correct values when I try to print each value in the console.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
line, = ax.plot([],[])

semi_major_axis = 1
eccentricity = 0.1
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, num = 50)

point, = ax.plot(0,1, marker="o")

def frame(i):
    r=(semi_major_axis*(1-eccentricity**2)/(1-eccentricity*np.cos(i)))
    line.set_xdata(i)
    line.set_ydata(r)
    return line,


ax.set_rmax(semi_major_axis+1)
ax.set_rticks(np.linspace(0,semi_major_axis+1, num = 5))
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5) 


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=frame, frames=theta, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are plotting a point and not a line. The following code worked for me:

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

    semi_major_axis = 1
    eccentricity = 0.1
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=50)

    def frame(i):
        r = (semi_major_axis * (1 - eccentricity ** 2) / (1 - eccentricity * np.cos(i)))
        ax.plot(i,r,'b', marker='o')

    ax.set_rmax(semi_major_axis + 1)
    ax.set_rticks(np.linspace(0, semi_major_axis + 1, num=5))
    ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)

    animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=frame, frames=theta, interval=10)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hmmm, when I do that all the positions are animated as they appear. Is there a way to have those points blend into a continuous line? BTW thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Change the relevant parts to: `num_points = 50
    i = range(num_points)
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num=num_points)
    def frame(n):
        r = (semi_major_axis * (1 - eccentricity ** 2) / (1 - eccentricity * np.cos(theta[:n+1])))
        ax.plot(theta[:n+1], r, 'b')`
and `animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=frame, frames=i, interval=10)`